# Microsoft Graph API: How to detected if Mail has been moved from another folder into an observed one (Mail/Delta Queries/Subscription)

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks

We currently migrating our .Net Application from EWS to Graph API using [msgraph-sdk-dotnet](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)

Primarily we are using [message-delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/message-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Requests to observe mail folders in order to detect incoming mails. So far so good.

### Migrating from EWS

When using EWS we were able to detect moved mail events/actions and to distinguish these mails from new incoming (new sent) mails. So far, we didn't figure out who this can be achieved by using MS Graph API.

### About use cases

There are use cases where we must distinguish a newly sent email from a Mail which has been moved/dragged from another folder into the observed one manually by any user (via Outlook). This use case scenario includes the following flow: Let's say the inbox is the observed folder, a new incoming mail has been sent to the mailbox and the mail has been detected by our delta request observer.

Then the user decides to move this mail into another custom but not observed folder using Outlook. Finally, the user decides to drag this mail back into the observed folder. Now we'd like to have a solid strategy at hand to detect this mail as moved (not as sent or updated, we need to distinguish these states).

*Hint*: This flow demonstrates why we can't really rely on *isRead*: Users can use a client (e. g. Outlook) to mark an any mail as read, which is most likely the case when you drag a mail from folder to folder.

### How to detected a moved mail?

Are there any properties from Mail Resource which can be used to identify if a mail has been moved specifically? Maybe something not mentioned in the public API documentation (ODATA, something which can be extracted by folderIds etc.?) or something which is supported by beta API version? Any ideas?

We also investigated the [subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource but did not find a specific changeType which specifically reflected a moved mail.

How should we resolve these issues? Any ideas how to develop a solid detection strategy for moved mails using Graph API?

Thx for any hint, advice or help you can give

Comment: How did you do this before in EWS and why is the distinction important? How would you classify an email in the Inbox folder created on the client side in Outlook by the POP3 provider?

Comment: EWS provides the `EventType.Moved` for this. 
Even if we'd use the [subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0) ressource it only supports `changeType`-s Created, Updated or Deleted. 
We tag all incoming mails using a `singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty`. We need a way to distiguish moved mails from sent mails because a moved mail must re-trigger our workflow and we cannot rely on our custom property, because user with access to an observerd folder can move all mails already marked mails.

Answer (score 0):

I have started looking at the lastModifiedDateTime property.  It appears that when the message is first received, the lastModifiedDateTime is 1-2 seconds after the receivedDateTime.  When the message is moved to another mail folder, receivedDateTime stays constant, but obviously the lastModifiedDateTime changes.  I am still looking at the Microsoft docs to find everywhere the lastModifiedDateTime property is changed.